can't append to table using sql alchemy and multiprocessing, get error that table exists
I am using sql alchemy to append data to a table in sql server. I am also running it in multiprocessing.
for benchmarking the same code is run sequentially, and runs without issue.
when I run the multiprocessing section of code, I receive the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'multiprocessing_test' in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE test (
        val BIGINT NULL,
        res BIGINT NULL,
        ins DATETIME NULL
)

I do not know why we are trying to create a new table, when I explicitly state an append. this is a concern, as I do not want to start a long process, and have it interrupted partway through. Annoyingly, if I drop the table in SQL and run a second time, it works without error.
Is there a way to stop this from happening?
code used:
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import numpy as np

engine = create_engine(database_con, fast_executemany=True)
con = engine.connect()

def sum_square(number):
    s=0
    for i in range(number):
        s+=i*i
    pd.DataFrame({'val':[number], 'res':[s],'ins':[pd.Timestamp.now()]}).to_sql(
            name='test',
            con=con,
            if_exists="append",
            index=False
        )
    con.commit()
    return(s)

def sum_square_w_mp(numbers):
    start_time = time.time()
    p=Pool()
    result = p.map(sum_square, numbers)

    p.close()
    p.join()

    end_tmke = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'Processing {len(numbers)} numbers took {end_tmke} time using multiprocessing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = range(100000)
    sum_square_w_mp(numbers)


Have you seen this?
